# How to Display child post on his parent post with thumbnail and content in WordPress

Tags: custom-post-types, children

I am trying to display child post in his parent's post with thumbnail and content. I also created a custom post for products and manage to display only parent post in custom template product.php. Now I want to display all the child of the parents. here is my code.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Product Page 
 *
 * Template for displaying a page just with the header and footer area and a "naked" content area in between.
 * Good for landingpages and other types of pages where you want to add a lot of custom markup.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */
get_header();
?>
<section class="inArea">
<div class="container">

    <div class="col-md-12 inconA wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.3s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 0.3s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">

        <h1 class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="1s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 1s; animation-name: fadeInDown;">our PRODUCTS</h1>  
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="products wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.6s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 0.6s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php
            $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'products', 'paged' => $paged, 'post_parent' => 0, 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));

            if ($query->have_posts()) :
                ?>
                <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?> 
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight" data-wow-duration="1s" data-wow-delay="0.9s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1s; animation-delay: 0.9s; animation-name: fadeInRight;">
                        <div class="products_cat">
                            <div class="img_cls"> 
                                <?php
                                if (has_post_thumbnail()) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                                    the_post_thumbnail('full');
                                }
                                ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
                <!-- show pagination here -->
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
<?php else : ?>
<!-- show 404 error here -->
<?php endif; ?>


<?php
get_footer();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check I understood your question, you want to display child posts under each parent post?

In that case you have to write one more `WP_Query` inside your `while` loop, with parent as current post in loop.

Something like:

```
        if ($query->have_posts()) :
            ?>
            <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); 

?> 
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight">
                    <div class="products_cat">
                        <div class="img_cls"> 
                            <?php
                               if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                                   the_post_thumbnail('full');
                               }?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
                             endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Edit:

Make a file single-products.php and add

```
$child_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'products', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'posts_per_page' => '-1'));
                           while ($child_query ->have_posts()) : $child_query ->the_post();
?> 
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 wow fadeInRight">
                    <div class="products_cat">
                        <div class="img_cls"> 
                            <?php
                               if (has_post_thumbnail()) { 
                                   the_post_thumbnail('full');
                               }?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <h2 class="title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
                           endwhile;
```

Please check syntax errors and add necessary code which haven't specified. Sorry I lost track of indentations after so many edits.

Comment: Not display any child it just show the featured image and content only of the parents.

Comment: Did you add the display code for `$child_query` loop?

Comment: yes, can you just help me for writing the qurey

Comment: Query is already there, I don't understand what you want.

Comment: but it does not display child post.instead, it displays only featured image and their content only.

Comment: Try edited code

Comment: edit code only shows child post, not a parent post. I want to display parent post and when the user clicks on the parent post it shows their child post only with their feature image and content.

Comment: So you want to display child pots on separate page?

Comment: yes I want to display child post on separate page.

Comment: it will not redirect to single-products.php.